# Printing an NSString

Tags: objective-c

What's the correct way to print an NSString in Objective-C? A lot of examples use NSLog(), but according to the documentation:

> NSLog is a FoundationKit function for printing debug statements to the console.
>   ...
>   NSLog works basically like:
>     fprintf(stderr, format_string, args ...);

Which to me is a bit like the _TRACE macro in Win32/C++. I don't want to print to stderr, I want to print to stdout.  There are people who suggest using printf() as follows:

```
printf("%s", [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

But this seems like an extra level on indirection to get the NSString printed, and it doesn't "feel" like the solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well this *is* the solution.

Since `printf` is a pure C function, it won't recognize the Objective-C objects. (NSLog's formatter is distinct from printf's one.) Therefore, you have to convert it into a C string before formatting.

BTW you can use `[str UTF8String]` instead of `[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`.

Comment: I understand `printf` is a pure C function, but I find it weird that you have to use it to print an NSString, rather than Core Foundation having a text IO library.

Answer (score 29):

Spewing stuff to `stdout` is actually a pretty rare thing to do in Cocoa, given that almost all projects are GUI in nature.   There are relatively few projects that are built as command line tools or otherwise need to deal with `stdout`.

However, the Foundation does provide the means to write to stdout. Specifically, `NSFileHandle` has `fileHandleWithStandardOutput` which gives you a file handle that can write to `stdout`.

From there, it is a matter of converting the `NSString` to an `NSData` and writing it.

Quite a few steps, but easily wrapped up in a reusable function:

```
void MyLog(NSString *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString *formattedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: format
                                                  arguments: args];
    va_end(args);
    [[NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardOutput]
        writeData: [formattedString dataUsingEncoding: NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding]];
    [formattedString release];
}
```

Comment: NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding?

Comment: sorry for nagging, but how do insert a '\n' between the log lines like that? don't want to waste too many cycles in such logging facility.

Comment: Ah, and maybe you know why the other method (using prinff("%s\n", [formattedString UTFString]) emits all kinds of junk into my printed lines?

Comment: probably because you're passing a unicode string to something expecting an ASCII string.

If you're using printf, just print a newline.  Performance is already hosed anyway.

Answer (score 10):

C string (UTF8String) is a pointer to a structure inside the string object.

```
NSString *str = @"Hello, World.";
printf("%s\n", [str UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll find these adequate for your needs:

```
// print to stdout
static void NSPrint(NSString *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];

    va_end(args);

    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", [string UTF8String]);

#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    [string release];
#endif
}

// print to stderr
static void NSPrintErr(NSString *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];

    va_end(args);

    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", [string UTF8String]);

#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    [string release];
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the custom file handler or write a macro yourself.

Tip: when NSLog prints out an object it uses object's `debugDescription` method. You could override this method for your custom `NSObject` subclasses to print custom debugInfo to stdout.

Comment: Awesome! Definitely did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

I just do:

```
define NSPrintf(...)   printf( "%s", [[NSString stringWithFormat: __VA_ARGS__] UTF8String] )
```

Then i can use it as:

```
NSPrintf( @"Sorry %@, I can't do that\n", name );
```