# Can I cast GameKit's peerID to uint32_t

Tags: c++, objective-c, gamekit, uint32

I am using GameKit for networking in my C++ application (created an Objective-C class for managing GameKit networking), but the problem is that GameKit uses NSString (not a C++ type) to identify peers (peerID). I have tested GameKit a lot and in my practice peerID is always a number (eg. 754569949). Is it safe to lexically cast peerID to uint32_t? Are there any cases where peerID is not a number?

Comment: Casting would give you the address in memory. Just convert NSString to something you can use? I think this gives you a char* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216266/printing-an-nsstring

Comment: With cast I meant lexical cast (edited post). The problem is that for compatibility with other parts of code, I need to identify clients by integer, not string

Comment: if the problem is `NSString` is not C++ type, you can use `std::string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of parts to your question: 1) parsing an int from `peerID` string; 2) maintaining association between your internals ids and `peerID`s.

If you need to get `peerID` into your C++ code and then be able to convert it back to `NSString` for use with GameKit framework, you shouldn't make any more assumptions about `peerID`'s contents than the official docs provide.

In other words, if you absolutely have to use ints, provide a way to map `peerID`s to your internal identifiers. But keep `peerID`s around and associated with your identifiers to be able to map the other way -- from your id back to `NSString`.

Making a map of `NSString -> uint32_t` might be one way to go about it.

The above mostly covers the 2nd part I mentioned in the first sentence. Now let's consider if it's save to parse `peerID` as an integer.

If you need to guarantee that a particular `peerID` will always map to the same `uint32_t`, you either assume `peerID` represents a number that will always fit into `uint32_t`, or you compute a hash of the string. There are problems with both approaches. Such a short hash might have collisions in real use. On the other hand, your system might brake one day when Apple decides to extend their `peerID`s to also include letters.

So I can't really make a decision for you, I've just tried to lay out the possibilities you might want to consider. I'd strongly suggest you to find a way to use original `peerID`, possibly converted to a C++ string type.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that for compatibility with other parts of code, I need to identify clients by integer, not string

If you have to get an integer out of these strings, in the absence of any guarantee it will always be a number, simply build a table of known IDs and assign indexes to them.

```
57483829 => 0
42937422 => 1
3333fghh => 2
```

You could use two `std::map`s to quickly convert between the two representations.

Simply convert the `NSString` to a string that's more C++ friendly. Alternatively, do the translation and maintain the indexes in Objective-C first and you can give your C++ code an index.